# Fallo Consulta SQL desde AJAX ?¿?¿

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

tengo este código en PHP:

```
function getPedidos(){
  $mysqli = getConn();
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `historial`";
  $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    $indices = '<table align='center'>
                <tr>
                    <th>NumP</th>
                    <th>Referenia</td>
                    <th>Detalles</th>
                    <th>Tipo</th>
                </tr>';

  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $indices = '<tr>
                    <td>" .$row[npedido]. "</td>
                    <td>" .$row[referencia]. "</td>
                    <td>" .$row[detalles]. "</td>
                    <td>" .$row[tipo]. "</td>
                </tr>';
  }

  $indices = '</table>';
  return $indices;
}

echo getPedidos();
```

Al que llamo desde el siguiente código de AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php/cargar_historial.php'
  })
  .done(function(listas_rep){
    $('#historial').html(listas_rep)
  })
  .fail(function(){
    alert('Hubo un errror al cargar el historial de pedidos')
  })
})
```

** Lo que yo pienso... es que se me ha ido la mano al crear la tabla en php **

El ajax, me pasa por .fail, cosa, que no encuentro el fallo. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar? ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Probablemente el error esta en la definición de `$indices` específicamente aquí `align='center'` usas comillas simple en ves de dobles o escaparlas y recuerda que para concatenar contenido es `$indices .=` y no `$indices =` de lo contrario solo sobrescribes el contenido

Comment: Vaya, se me había pasado el .= y ahora veo las 'center' mal puestas, el caso es que ahora me saca impreso en la tabla " .$row[npedido]. " en vez del valor LOL!, ¿Help?

Comment: Listo!, era de nuevo problema de las f*** comillas dobles y simples, me había mareado, gracias por detectar estos erroes!! muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Si has resuelto tu pregunta deberías poner la respuestas como una respuesta con la solución, para que los usuarios que entren vean que ha quedado resuelta y en dado caso de que a alguien le sirva ver como lo resolviste.

Comment: Listo!! ¡Gracia a todos! @Sr1871

Comment: Voy a revertir tu edición, ya que las soluciones deben ir en el campo de respuestas, y no como una edicion a tu pregunta, ya que no se entiende si esta resuelta o no, y no se sabe que cosa resolviste de esa forma. Tambien, si la solucion es solo un problema de sintaxis, considera si puede llegar a servile a un futuro usuario o no.